# making callback interface is mandatory in java for callback?

Tags: java, android, callback

In some languages, you can pass functions (callbacks) to a function-foo, and let function-foo to call the callback function.

In android, java world, I see tutorials that creates callback-class and pass the instance of the callback-class.

I could certainly use it, but it's just more hassle to define the callback-interface-class and pass it.

Do I have to define a custom callback interface everytime I need to use callback functionality?

Is there a predefined callback-interface I could use at least?

** edit **

Is there a some predefined `PredefinedCallback` which I can use?

```
fooClass.fooMethod(new PredfinedCallback() {
  public void onComplete(JsonObject result) {
  };
})


void fooMethod(PredefinedCallback callback) {
  onSomeAsyncWorkComplete(
      callback.onComplete(result);
  );
}
```

Ion's `FutureCallback` seems to be a good form I can use.
Although I don't know how I could use the FutureCallback in my code not as callback for ion request.

Comment: Define "easily". What's wrong with the reflective approach?

Comment: just sprang into my mind there might be a function passing in java as in other languages.. I guess not :(

Comment: I edited the op a bit.

Comment: If you could have that predefined callback, how would it look like?

Comment: In my opinion, java's callback(actually the Interface pattern) could not be compared to others (especially javascript's callback). But you could define your common interface to use by various classes. It's free and it depends on your usage.

Comment: It may be a tad more verbose, to create the anonymous class object, but IDEs (Eclipse, Android Studio) will generate this code for you.  Once you get used to this, it really is no hassle at all.

Answer (score 0):

In JVM languages, callbacks are implemented as method calls on interfaces (usually) or abstract classes (rarely); there are no free-floating functions unattached to objects. (Functional-type libraries usually define an interface `Function` with a single method such as `apply`, and then it's possible to pass `Function` objects around like any other object.)

Java as of Java 7 (the latest available in Android) doesn't provide any convenience features for implementing callbacks. You may be interested in using [Groovy](http://www.mscharhag.com/groovy/creating-android-apps-with-groovy), which does support using closures (inline functions) as implementations for callback functions.